# What is the SQL Loader equivalent in SQL Server for extracting a database from SQL Server to the same server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to replicate or copy a database in SQL Server 2014 in order to create a sandbox. I know SQL Loader does that for Oracle. Is there an equivalent tool in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

We use `bcp.exe` as Loader program. It is located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn`

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to create a database backup.  Once the backup is completed, restore that backup under a different name.

Steps:

1. right click database from SSMS
2. Tasks -> Backup
3. Follow wizard
4. Once backup is complete, right click databases folder from the server  and select restore database
5. Follow wizard, ensuring you're restoring the database to a new name.

Here are more detailed tutorials:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Note that if your intention is to test an application with the copied DB, ensure you're updating connection strings and whatnot to point to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this in following ways:

1.Stop the sql server, copy the *.mdf file locating it right clicking on existing database -> properties from the server to the destination sever and attach it to the destination server using SSMS.

2.Create SSIS package and execute that using [DTExec.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).You can create a .bat file ,configure and call the DTexec.exe from that .bat file.This will be alternatve to oracle SQL loader for ETL tasks.